# PHP checking for 5pm of a certain date

Tags: php, date

I am currently trying to compare the current time to 5pm of a date that will be calculated using a date a user will select. I have tried different combinations and googled it but for some reason I cannot seem to figure out how to place 5pm on to the selected date.

```
$expressFeeDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days', $arrivaldate_converted));// this line outputs 2018-01-08 for this current example
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");// this line out puts the current date and time 2018-01-05 10:54:43am
```

I would like to after the user selects the their date calculate the expressFeeDate with as it is in the variable above and then have another variable in which it take that date and outputs  2018-01-08 05:00:00pm.

Thank you all feedback welcomed.

Comment: I guess `date("Y-m-d", $expressDate) . " 05:00:00pm"` could do the trick

Comment: @LatinSuD how would I covert the current time to the same format to compare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create 2 DateTime Objects and use the Datetime diff method to get the interval back.

```
$selectedDate = new \DateTime('2018-1-1');
$selectedDate->setTime(0, 17);
$today = new \DateTime('now');

$interval = $selectedDate->diff($today);
var_dump($interval); exit;
```

This returns a DateInterval Object looking like this:

```
  object(DateInterval)[959]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 4
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 10
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 4
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

Now you can simply cherry pick attributes and use whatever you need.